# incrementing inside a javascript object while toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a program where I toggle various items and want it to keep track of how many times I have toggled a particular item. I created a `function` that would use the `id` of each object and toggle it based on the `id`.  However, when I try to count how many times that particular `id` is toggled, all I get is the total count of all toggles, not just that `id`.

Here are my items I wish to toggle:

```
<p id="demo1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">demo1</p>
<p id="demo2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">demo2</p>
<p id="demo3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">demo3</p>
```

Here is the JavaScript that toggles and counts how many times it's toggled:

```
var pop = {};
function reply_click(bid) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#" + bid).toggleClass("active");
    if (typeof pop.bid === "undefined") {
        pop.bid = 0;}
    else {pop.bid = pop.bid + 1};
    document.getElementById(bid).innerHTML = pop.bid + " " + bid;
});
}
```

Can anyone either fix my code or give me an alternate method of incrementing individual items instead of all of them?  Thanks!

Comment: `pop[bid]` to dynamically set or access a property of an object

Comment: seriously?  how did i not figure that out!  it works now.  thanks!

Comment: just a learning process.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. Try this:

```
pop[bid]
```

instead of this:

```
pop.bid
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone either fix my code or give me an alternate method of
>   incrementing individual items instead of all of them?

You are invoking the method which creates a event handler `document.ready` which is unlikely to get fired.

```js
var pop = {};

$( "p" ).click( function(){
  var id = $(this).attr( "id" ) ;
  pop[ id ] = pop[ id ] || 0;
  pop[ id ]++;
  $(this).html( "Click counter" + pop[ id ] );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo1">demo1</p>
<p id="demo2">demo2</p>
<p id="demo3">demo3</p>
```